# Case insensitive LIKE clause in Pervasive SQL

Tags: pervasive-sql

I'm attempting to write a query in Pervasive SQL which matches on a "LIKE" clause, but without case sensitivity.

As an example, I want the following query to match both "john", "John", and "JOHN".  Currently, this is case sensitive.

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE ?
```

In T-SQL, I would just wrap UPPER around both parts of the WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER(?)
```

However, placing any functions to the right of the WHERE clause fails with a syntax error.

How can I achieve a case-insensitive search?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to change the case of the value that's coming in before you create the SQL Statement.  Something like this C#ish code:

```
string value = "world";
sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE = '" + value.ToUpper();
```

Or, even better use Parameters and set your value before you set the parameter.

You're right, having a function on the right side the `LIKE` will cause a Syntax Error.  You might want to report it as a bug to Actian.